# ffmpeg several streams with different video and audio setting using --filter_complex and tee pseudo muxer from same source

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, streaming, codec

I'm capturing video with embeded audio from decklink mini recorder and need to create 6 different streams. I've created the filter for the video and it works, but cannot figure it out how to set different audio setting for each stream. I need some of the videos to use aac on 44100hz and the rest to use opus with 48000hz. Could anyone help with that?

**This is what I use now:**

```
 /usr/bin/ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 2048 -f decklink -video_input sdi -audio_input embedded -i 'DeckLink Mini Recorder 4K' -threads 4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fps=25,split=6[s720][s540][s180][l720][l360][l180]; \
[s720]scale=-2:720[v720]; \
[s540]scale=-2:540[v540]; \
[s180]scale=-2:180[v180]; \
[l720]scale=-2:720[lv720]; \
[l360]scale=-2:540[lv540]; \
[l180]scale=-2:180[lv180]" \
-map "[v720]" -bufsize:v:0 800k -maxrate:v:0 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v540]" -bufsize:v:1 500k -maxrate:v:1 1400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v180]" -bufsize:v:2 100k -maxrate:v:2 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv720]" -bufsize:v:3 800k -maxrate:v:3 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv540]" -bufsize:v:4 200k -maxrate:v:4 700k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv180]" -bufsize:v:5 100k -maxrate:v:5 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map a:0 \
-af "pan=mono|c0=FL" -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -profile:v:0 main -bf 0 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -f tee \
"[select=\'v:0,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://........................|\
 [select=\'v:0,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://........................|\
 [select=\'v:1,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://........................|\
 [select=\'v:3,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://.......................|\
 [select=\'v:4,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://.......................|\
 [select=\'v:5,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://......................."
```

**When I add the -acodec and -ar options it seems that it gets the parameters from the last -map option:**

```
-map "[v720]" -acodec aac -b 128k -ar 44100 -bufsize:v:0 800k -maxrate:v:0 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v540]" -acodec aac -b 96k -ar 44100 -bufsize:v:1 500k -maxrate:v:1 1400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v180]" -acodec aac -b 96k -ar 44100 -bufsize:v:2 100k -maxrate:v:2 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv720]" -acodec libopus -b 128k -ar 48000 -bufsize:v:3 800k -maxrate:v:3 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv540]" -acodec libopus -b 96k -ar 48000 -bufsize:v:4 200k -maxrate:v:4 700k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv180]" -acodec libopus -b 96k -ar 48000 -bufsize:v:5 100k -maxrate:v:5 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map a:0 \
-af "pan=mono|c0=FL" -profile:v:0 main -bf 0 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -f tee \
"[select=\'v:0,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://...........................................|\
 [select=\'v:0,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://...........................................|\
 [select=\'v:1,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://...........................................|\
 [select=\'v:3,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://...........................................|\
 [select=\'v:4,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://...........................................|\
 [select=\'v:5,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtsp://..........................................."
```

**I get this in return:**

```
[flv @ 0x55df601d4f40] FLV does not support sample rate 48000, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)
[flv @ 0x55df601d4f40] Audio codec opus not compatible with flv
[tee @ 0x55df5cd5bf40] Slave muxer #0 failed, aborting.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Function not implemented
```

Answer (score 1):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

you already split it into 6 channels and you can define the acodec on the individual -map tag using -acodec tag.

Comment: I've added some more info in my post. Check it, please.

Comment: So the error clearly state that you have a bitrate issue.  Did it not work when you switch to 44100?

Comment: Also the second error is saying that you have a write permission issue.  I'm not sure how switch to single channel then split would help you with those errors.  Please correct the answer so it's not misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that by splitting only the video and adding -acodec, -b, -ar to each map is not working and the ffmpeg takes the last options of these parameters as default for all maps. I also trie to set -acodec:a:0 etc, but doesn't seem to work also.

Finally, after a lot of researching and testing I've added [a:0]asplit=2... and then mapped each audio separately. also put -codec:a:0 instead of -acodec... and it finally worked. Hope it'll help somebody else too. Here is the final command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 2048 -f decklink -video_input sdi -audio_input embedded -i 'DeckLink Mini Recorder 4K' -threads 4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fps=25,split=6[s720][s540][s180][l720][l360][l180]; \
[s720]scale=-2:720[v720]; \
[s540]scale=-2:540[v540]; \
[s180]scale=-2:180[v180]; \
[l720]scale=-2:720[lv720]; \
[l360]scale=-2:540[lv540]; \
[l180]scale=-2:180[lv180]; \
[0:a]asplit=2[opus][aac]" \
-map "[lv720]" -bufsize:v:0 800k -maxrate:v:0 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv540]" -bufsize:v:1 200k -maxrate:v:1 700k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[lv180]" -bufsize:v:2 100k -maxrate:v:2 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v720]" -bufsize:v:3 800k -maxrate:v:3 2500k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v540]" -bufsize:v:4 500k -maxrate:v:4 1400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v180]" -bufsize:v:5 100k -maxrate:v:5 400k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[opus]" -codec:a:0 libopus -ar:a:0 48000 -b:a:0 128k \
-map "[aac]" -codec:a:1 aac -ar:a:1 44100 -b:a:1 128k \
-profile:v:0 main -bf 0 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 25 -bf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -f tee \
"[select=\'v:0,a:0\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://.......................|\
[select=\'v:1,a:0\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://.......................|\
[select=\'v:2,a:0\':f=fifo:fifo_format=rtsp:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://.......................|\
[select=\'v:3,a:1\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://.......................|\
[select=\'v:3,a:1\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://.......................|\
[select=\'v:4,a:1\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://......................."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to 5a68656e4e6975's comment. It appeared to be too long for the comments section, so I'm putting it here :)

When I use -acodec it takes its value from the last -map and puts it to all maps. It is absolutely not a bitrate problem. FLV does not support opus handles only one of these audio frequencies: 44100hz, 22050hz, 11025hz. On the other hand OPUS codec supports only 48000hz. Limelight CDN needs a flv input with 41000hz audio encoded with aac, and Wowza Streaming Engine needs audio to be encoded with opus codec and 48khz so it can restream it through WebRTC (I don't want the server to transcode). So this write permission error was due to feeding Limelight with opus and 48khz audio. With the code from my answer everything works great. And I'm switching to single channel because my microphone is connected only to the left channel of the ATEM HD TV Switch, but I need to hear on both speakers/headphones. And no, the ATEM does not have option to copy the audio from one channel to another, that's why I'm doing it in ffmpeg.